# Ruby method returns unexpected value

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I have a method that returns the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers which is less than `smaller_than`. It should run as fast as possible.

A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The smallest palindrome made of two 3-digit numbers is 101101, which is the product of 143 * 707.

This is my code:

```
def palindrome(smaller_than)
  max = 0

  999.downto(143).each do |x|
    999.downto(707).each do |y|
      break if (max > x * y) || (smaller_than < x * y)
      max = x * y if x * y == (x * y).to_s.reverse.to_i
    end
  end

  return max
end

t = Time.now
puts palindrome(800000)
puts "Took #{Time.now-t}"
```

This gives me `723327` instead of `793397`.

If I change my code to this:

```
def palindrome(smaller_than)
  max = 0

  999.downto(143).each do |x|
    999.downto(707).each do |y|
      break if max > x * y
      max = x * y if (x * y == (x * y).to_s.reverse.to_i) && (smaller_than > x * y)
    end
  end

  return max
end

t = Time.now
puts palindrome(800000)
puts "Took #{Time.now-t}"
```

...it gives me the right value of `793397`.

The second method works but it's too slow. Why does the faster, first, method return the wrong value?

Comment: Any program can be made very fast, if it doesn't have to work correctly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your first version is that it's breaking from inner loop where it shouldn't. Here's a working version that is almost as fast as a non-working one.

```
def palindrome2(smaller_than)
  max = 0

  999.downto(143).each do |x|
    999.downto(707).each do |y|
      product = x * y
      break if max > product
      next if smaller_than < product
      max = product if product.to_s == product.to_s.reverse
    end
  end

  return max
end
```

### Also,

You can achieve the same speedup if you just rearrange the conditions in your check, to enable [short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

```
  # max = x * y if (x * y == (x * y).to_s.reverse.to_i) && (smaller_than > x * y)
  max = x * y if (smaller_than > x * y) && (x * y == (x * y).to_s.reverse.to_i)
```